# What are the advantages of Space reclamation by DB2?

Tags: database, db2

IBM DB2 allows Space reclamation since Version 9.7. [Space Reclamation](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.luw.wn.doc/doc/c0055000.html)
I did not understand how it can help me.
Which benefits does this princip bring?? Which advantages has this process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do inserts to the database, the file physically expands to accommodate new data. After you make deletes to it, the engine only marks those deleted rows, not shrinking the file physically, because operation on a large dataset would be time/resource costly.

To address this issue various vendors offers ways to physically compact data, removing unnecessary data from a physical file at a givven time, ussually performed during backups...